# Azure devops boards REST API - move ticket between columns

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm testing out the Azure Boards rest API. I can currently create, delete and get items successfully, however I can't seem to move them between columns.

This is my request
`https://{{AzureBoardsToken}}@{{AzureBoardsPath}}/_apis/wit/workitems/8907?api-version=6.0-preview.3`

with a payload of

```
[
  {
    "op": "move",
    "path": "{no idea what to put here}",
    "from": "{no idea what to put here}",
    "value": "{not sure if this is relevant for this operation}"
  }
]
```

I don't find the documentation particularly useful as it assumes you know what those properties mean and where to get them.

Any help would be highly appreciated! The idea is to then integrate it in nodejs

Comment: have you tried doing it manually in the browser and observe the networking requests in the Developer Tools?

Comment: I did, but the API looks fairly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

To move workitem to another column you have to change `"WEF_{id}_Kanban.Column"` field.

Use PATCH to update your workitem with body:

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/fields/WEF_F9DCD9224F6E466499435017DB7D2D07_Kanban.Column",
        "value": "<column name>"
    }
]
```

### Solution 2

To move workitem to another column you have to change it "state". This only works if you assigned that state to the column.

Use PATCH to update your workitem with body:

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "value": "<column name>"
    }
]
```

doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

EDIT (Adding new state):

Go to organization settings -> Process -> choose your workflow -> choose item type -> states -> new state (Add "In progress" here)

[image]

Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#add-a-workflow-state

Then go to column setting on Kanban Board and associate new state with column

[image]

Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-columns?view=azure-devops#update-kanban-column-to-state-mappings

After that try using API REST to change state, it should work

Comment: Got better results by using the payload you provided (was using op as "move") and a different path, however I'm still getting an error back. My column is called  "In Progress" and I get the following: ""ErrorMessage": "The field 'State' contains the value 'In Production' that is not in the list of supported values","

Comment: Same for the "Done" column, so I'm assuming it doesn't ready from how I called my columns but by an ID that I can't seem to find?

Comment: @DjayC I edited the post with adding new state to workflow and associating it with column on Kanban Board

Comment: Thank you Tomasz, that worked beautifully. I also found out there’s a property that looks like {guid}.Kanbanboard.Column which you can set to the name of the column you want to move your ticket to, which works out of the box!

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how does one get all items in a column? The REST api expects you to dictate what items you want to get back, while my use case is getting whatever is in there, which is unknown until I do the request

Comment: Nice to know about this Kanbanboard.Column property. I wil add it to the anwser for everyone to notice this solution. If you want to ask another question create a different post, so others could find it from search.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the `System.State` of a task I had to alter the `System.Reason` as well. For some reason the two fields are connected and both changes are necessary to trigger a transition from one column to the other.

For example to change a task from the state `To Do` to `In Progress` use the [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#operation) REST API with the following request body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "In Progress"
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/fields/System.Reason",
    "value": "Work started"
  }
]
```